# How can I make script for recursive downloading all empty files?

Tags: vbscript

I need to develop the VBScript that donwload all files with size equals 0 from drive C. I have made following script:

```
Dim oFSO 
Dim sDirectoryPath
Dim oFolder  
Dim oFileCollection
Dim oFile
Dim oFolderCollection
Dim n
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
sDirectoryPath = "C:\"
set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(sDirectoryPath)
set oFolderCollection = oFolder.SubFolders
set oFileCollection = oFolder.Files
For each oFile in oFileCollection
    IF oFile.Size = 0 Then
        oFile.Delete(true)
    END IF
Next
```

But this script deletes files from root directory of drive C only! I need to use recusrive in this code, but I'm new in VBScript and don't know how I can do it. Please, I hope you will help me. Thank you.

Comment: What about something like this: http://www.wisesoft.co.uk/scripts/vbscript_recursive_file_delete_by_extension.aspx

Answer (score 0):

here a tested and working script

```
set oFso = createobject("scripting.filesystemobject")
sDirectorypath = "c:\testing"
delete_empty_files(sDirectorypath)

sub delete_empty_files(folder)
  set oFolder = oFso.getfolder(folder)
  for each oFile in oFolder.files
    if oFile.size = 0 then
      wscript.echo " deleting " & oFile.path
      oFile.delete(true)
    end if
  next
  for each oSubFolder in oFolder.subfolders
    delete_empty_files(oSubFolder)
  next
end sub
```