# VBS check a list of files

Tags: vbscript

I have this script but would like to expand it to check a list of files and also existence of mapped drive R: and map if not there.

FileA.txt
FileB.txt
FileD.txt
FileE.txt
FileF.dll
FileG.dll

```
Const OverwriteExisting = TRUE

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set objLocalFile = objFSO.GetFile("C:\SCRIPT\SCRIPTTEXT.txt")
dtmLocalDate = objLocalFile.DateLastModified

Set objServerFile = objFSO.GetFile("R:\SCRIPT\SCRIPTTEXT.txt")
dtmServerDate = objServerFile.DateLastModified

If dtmLocalDate < dtmServerDate Then
    objFSO.CopyFile objServerFile.Path, objLocalFile.Path, OverwriteExisting
End If
```

The snippet does not work if not drive not there with an error “this network connection does not exist” but remaps ok.

```
> Set WSHNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
> 
> WSHNetwork.RemoveNetworkDrive "R:","True","True"
> 
> WSHNetwork.MapNetworkDrive "R:", "\\192.168.1.103\","True"
```

Comment: Must the solution be in VBScript? It would seem that this problem be far easier solved using BATch files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't map, do the comparison directly with the url

```
on error resume next
path = "\\192.168.1.103\SCRIPT\SCRIPTTEXT.txt"
if objFSO.fileExist(path)
  Set objServerFile = objFSO.GetFile(path)
  dtmServerDate = objServerFile.DateLastModified
  if dtmLocalDate < dtmServerDate Then
    objFSO.CopyFile objServerFile.Path, objLocalFile.Path, OverwriteExisting
  end if
else
  objFSO.CopyFile objServerFile.Path, objLocalFile.Path
end if
```

Comment: Thanks for this how can I loop it through FileA.txt, FileB.txt FileD.txt, FileE.txt, FileF.dll, FileG.dll the .dll s' are not in the same folder

Comment: see another answer of me which deletes empty files in a folder, use the same technique http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10450639/how-can-i-make-script-for-recursive-downloading-all-empty-files